# Docker: `bun --bun run vite build` does not write to docker file system

Tags: docker, vite, bun

I have a docker file to build a sveltekit app running on bun:

```
FROM oven/bun:1 as base

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# install dependencies into temp directory
# this will cache them and speed up future builds
FROM base AS install

RUN mkdir -p /temp/dev
COPY package.json bun.lockb /temp/dev/
RUN cd /temp/dev && bun install --frozen-lockfile

# install with --production (exclude devDependencies)
RUN mkdir -p /temp/prod
COPY package.json bun.lockb /temp/prod/
RUN cd /temp/prod && bun install --frozen-lockfile --production

# copy node_modules from temp directory
# then copy all (non-ignored) project files into the image
FROM install AS prerelease
COPY --from=install /temp/dev/node_modules node_modules
COPY . .

# [optional] tests & build
ENV NODE_ENV=production

RUN bun test
RUN bun --bun run vite build

# copy production dependencies and source code into final image
FROM base AS release
COPY --from=install /temp/prod/node_modules node_modules
COPY --from=prerelease /usr/src/app/build .

ARG PORT=3000

ENV PORT=$PORT

# run the app
USER bun
EXPOSE $PORT/tcp

ENTRYPOINT [ "bun", "--bun", "run", "index.js" ]
```

`bun --bun run vite build` runs fine, but does not write any files into the virtual directory. When docker wants to run `COPY --from=prerelease /usr/src/app/build .` it fails with:

```
 => ERROR [release 2/2] COPY --from=prerelease /usr/src/app/build .                                                                                                                                        0.0s
------
 > [release 2/2] COPY --from=prerelease /usr/src/app/build .:
------
Dockerfile:40
--------------------
  38 |     FROM base AS release
  39 |     COPY --from=install /temp/prod/node_modules node_modules
  40 | >>> COPY --from=prerelease /usr/src/app/build .
  41 |     
  42 |     ARG PUBLIC_SUPABASE_KEY
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref 59ffe7c5-8f84-47e9-abfa-e874ebd11c23::rhxl5rttggoine2xtli1r7jqs: "/usr/src/app/build": not found
```

Locally it works. I am not sure if this is a bug or if I am missing something in my Dockerfile. But I can't see what the issue would be.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)